# Циклический вывод чисел до 4

Tags: php, математика

Каким способом можно вывести числа от 1 до 4 в заданном промежутке?

Например:
Необходимо вывести числа от до 15 (количество)

Вывод:
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
3

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоаться оператором получения остатка от деления на 4

```
$i = 0;
for($i=0; $i<15; $i++) {
    echo $i%4+1 .' ';
}
```

Comment: а как можно получить последнее число не проходя циклом? например до 134, как угадать какое число будет последним?

Comment: например `(134-1)%4+1`

Comment: ты гений, спасибо большое!